# enclose js error.....Compilation successful but when i run executable file it shows error unexpected token illegal

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

[image]

Tell me how to resolve that problem . Thanks

Comment: `indexjs` appears to be an executable (`.exe`) file. Run it without node.

Comment: no. it's not working. It's in file format not in .exe format

Comment: it's working now ... i am using ./index instead of node ./index.js